# Connecting Netgear nighthawk x6s in AP mode with FIOS router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have the following setup:
coax > FIOS router > Switch > Asus WiFi router (working in AP mode only)

I would like to change the Asus WiFi router for Netgear Nighthawk X6S. However, I am unable to connect to its config panel. It is currently plugged into the same switch and it was assigned ip of 10.0.0.1 in order to avoid conflict with FIOS router. However, I get "site can't be reached". What other options should I try?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you have them physically connected with the ports from the first router to the second?

Comment: How did you assign the IP in the first place? Did you read the manual?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I ended up connecting to my Fios router and and accessed the config panel using the IP address of the AP mode router (i.e. Nighthawk) assigned by the Fios router.